# NUnit extending ICommandWrapper How do I wrap a TestCase?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I tried extending extending `ICommandWrapper`, following this article: https://www.skyrise.tech/blog/tech/extending-nunit-3-with-command-wrappers/. I figured out that I can also extend `TestAttribute` and it just works, then I tried extending `TestCaseAttribute`:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method), AllowMultiple = true]
public class MyTestCaseAttribute : TestCaseAttribute, IWrapSetUpTearDown
{
    private object[] _args;

    public MyTestCaseAttribute(params object[] args) : base(args)
    {
        _args = args;
    }

    public TestCommand Wrap(TestCommand command)
    {
        return new MyTestCommand(command, _args);
    }
}
```

`MyTestCommand` extends `DelegatingTestCommand`, just like in the article.
The problem is, if I add multiple `MyTestCaseAttribute`s to a test method, the test method gets wrapped by `MyTestCommand.Execute`'s code multiple times.

[EDIT] **Example:**
Suppose `MyTestCommand` looks like this:

```cs
public abstract class MyCommandDecorator : DelegatingTestCommand
{
    public override TestResult Execute(TestExecutionContext context)

    private object[] _testCaseArgs;

    protected TestCommandDecorator(TestCommand innerCommand, params object[] args) : base(innerCommand)
    {
        _testCaseArgs = args;
    }

    public override TestResult Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
    {
        DoSomething(_testCaseArgs);
        return context.CurrentResult = innerCommand.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

Suppose I decorate a test method with two `[MyTestCase]` attributes:

```cs
[MyTestCase(1)]
[MyTestCase(2)]
public void MyTest(int foo)
{
//...
}
```

The desired behaviour is something like:

```cs
DoSomething(1);
MyTest(1);
DoSomething(2);
MyTest(2);
```

But actual behaviour is:

```cs
DoSomething(2)
DoSomething(1)
MyTest(1)
DoSomething(2)
DoSomething(1)
MyTest(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Instead of extending `TestCaseAttribute`, I can extend `TestAttribute` and obtain the arguments to pass to the wrapper class from standard `TestCaseAttribute`s using `command.Test.Arguments`.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method), AllowMultiple = true]
public class MyTestAttribute : TestAttribute, IWrapSetUpTearDown
{
    public TestCommand Wrap(TestCommand command)
    {
        return new MyTestCommand(command, command.Test.Arguments);
    }
}
```

```cs
[TestCase(1)]
[TestCase(2)]
[MyTest]
public void MyTest(int foo)
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to your problem is this... C# allows you to decorate a method or a class with an attribute. But an individual test case doesn't exist outside of NUnit - there is no C# equivalent - so you can't decorate it.

IOW your two Attributes apply to the method and cause NUnit to use that method to generate two test cases. However, your attributes also implement ICommandWrapper, which causes NUnit to wrap any test cases it generates. One part of NUnit is looking for test cases to create another part is looking for attributes to wrap test cases. Those two parts are entirely separated.

That's why NUnit uses properties on the test case method to indicate things like Ignoring the case. It can't use an attribute because an attribute would apply to **every test case** generated by that method.

Hopefully, that explains what's happening.

To get past the problem, your command wrapper should only apply itself to a test that was generated by that particular instance of the attribute. That means you have to get involved in the creation of the test, at least to the extent that your attribute remembers the reference to the test it created. This is a bit complicated, but you should look at the code for TestCaseAttribute to see how the test case is created.